# Overwrite datatables's tr background color in bootstrap's dark-mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5 and datatables 1.13.

Bootstrap's `dark-table` row color/variable for odd rows seems unoverwritable.

See below, how I have added `td.text-center{background: yellow}` (green arrow) to all rows, but only the even rows show yellow:

---

[image]

---

The red arrow shows the bootstrap setting, and when I click the checkbox next to that variable I can finally all rows as yellow. But that's the only time. No amount of jQuery or css seem to overwrite this.

### A small symbolic list of the many things I have tried:

1. on datatables' rowCallback I gave each row and td a bg-warning class.
2. I have created a custom class with greater specificity than bootstrap's `...n-th-of-type(odd)`
3. In the console I gave a tr and td's the inline-style: `background:yellow !important`
4. I made everything have a transparent background and just the td have a background color.

Here's the only time I see all yellow - I have to uncheck the box for that variable:

[image]